# Keycloak: Invalid token issuer when running as docker service

Tags: spring, docker, keycloak

I have a problem:

`WWW-Authenticate Bearer realm="test", error="invalid_token", error_description="Invalid token issuer. Expected 'http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/test', but was 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/test'"`

My settings:

application.yml

```
keycloak:
  realm: test
  resource: api
  auth-server-url: http://keycloak:8080/auth
  ssl-required: external
  autodetect-bearer-only: true
  cors: true
  principal-attribute: preferred_username
  credentials:
    secret: 2b553733-8d5f-4276-8ace-17112ac7ac20
```

docker-compose.yml

```
keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:10.0.0
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - net
```

Auth url: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/auth
Token url: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/token

I understand why the problem exists, but I don`t understand how to fix it.

Comment: I believe you're running keycloak locally? Then replace `auth-server-url: http://keycloak:8080/auth` by `auth-server-url: http://localhost:8080/auth` in your application.

Comment: I had to use the `keycloak.proxy-url` setting https://christophewillemsen.com/2021/06/08/keycloak-invalid-token-issuer-when-running-locally-with-docker/

Answer (score 7):

Keycloak's Default Hostname Provider (https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#default-provider) has a property called frontendURL which should be set as the public URL on which Keycloak is exposed.

Setting frontendURL ensures that all front-channel URLs, like issuer, authorization_endpoint use the configured value as hostname in the URLs and back-channel URLs keep using hostname in the request.

Comment: Latest versions uses `KC_FRONTEND` or `KC_FRONTEND_URL`. Details here: https://www.keycloak.org/server/all-config

Answer (score 0):

I added 127.0.0.1 keycloak in hosts file and used http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/*** url to get the token. Now the JWT token contained the issuer as keycloak instead of localhost. I verified the token using jwt.io website. This resolved the mismatch in token issuer.